# What's the lenght of the segment $CE$ in the quadrilateral below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

(For reference) In the ABCD quadrilateral, $AB = 12, AD = 10, BC = 6$ and $BD =8$
Calculate $CE$, if $E$ is in $BD$ and $EB = 5$. $\angle BAD = \angle CBD$ (Answer: $4$)

My progress:
I believe that the solution is by auxiliary lines...
Tried to lengthen sides BC and AD forming the triangle
AFB, by Geogebra it would be an isosceles triangle $\angle A = \angle F , CF =CB \implies DC \perp CB $ but I couldn't demonstrate...

[image]

Comment: You can do without auxiliary lines, if you'll note that triangle ADB is similar to triangle BCE.

Comment: $\angle BAD = \angle CBE$ and sides of the angles in both triangles are in the ratio of $1:2$.

Comment: My previous comment solves the problem. But: if you'll find cos BAD from cosine theorem, then use it in triangle CBD, you'll get CD=$\sqrt{28}$, CD$^2$+CB$^2$=BD$^2$, so BCD is right angle.

Comment: @MathLover..I could use the similarity Ivan mentioned and therefore the similarity ratio would be $\frac{12}{6} = \frac{10}{5} = 2 \therefore CE = \frac{8}{2}=4$  ..is this thought correct?

Comment: @ACB..:) I will always prefer the geometric resolutions because the exercises are from a book where trigonometry is not used...and as Ivan gave the hint for the geometrical resolution when transcribing I will use the geometrical resolution...and as only his resolution was posted as a reply and was the first I will take as a reply

Comment: Your answer above is correct. But I suspect whether MathLover received a notification because you typed dots immediately after the name. (I didn't recieve a notification either because of that)

Comment: @petaarantes yes that is correct I did not see it earlier as I did not get a notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the triangle $ABD$ we have:
$$\small 
\cos(\angle{BAD})=\frac{AB^2+AD^2-BD^2}{2\cdot AB\cdot AD}=0.75
$$

Also we know that $\small \angle{BAD}=\angle{CBD}\implies\cos(\angle{BAD})=\cos(\angle{CBD})$.

Using the very well known **law of cosines**, we can determine $CE$:
$$\small 
CE^2=EB^2+CB^2-2\cdot EB\cdot CB\cdot \cos(\angle{CBD})\implies CE=4.
$$

Good luck!